# Trying to add elements at the same index for more than one list

Tags: python, list

Im trying to make a function that has a parameter which is a list of 4-element lists, that represents which team people approve.
The order of the inner( 4-element) list is ['team1', 'team2', 'team3', 'team4']

People will vote 'YES' for at least one teamand 'NO' for the other three. Each 'YES'counts for one vote.

The output is a list with the total amount of 'YES' for each team in the same order of the original order.

An example would be:

electing([['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO'],['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES'], ['YES', 'NO','NO','NO']])

which would return
([2,0,0,1])

Can you help me please..Im new to python and I just only made it to getting each persons vote count like [1,0,0,0] but I couldnt add each list to make one list.

Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Please show the code you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

```
vote1 = ['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO']
vote2 = ['NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES']
vote3 = ['YES', 'NO','NO','NO']

votelist = [vote1, vote2, vote3]

def electing(votelist):
    return [votes.count("YES") for votes in zip(*votelist)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but there can more than three inner lists. This is what I seem to be stumble on..

Comment: @user1828603, what happened when you tried to use this with more than 3 inner lists?

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have a `for` loop like most languages, and that can be a bit confusing to new users of this language. In cases like this (where you want to count from zero to some arbitrary length) you can use the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/range.html) function:

```
for i in range(4):
    ...
```

That is (roughly) the same as:

```
for i in [0,1,2,3]:
    ...
```

Use this and try to formulate your code, if you have more questions show what you've tried so far and we might be able to help you more.

P.S. For a more advanced way of doing what you want, I'd suggest looking at the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) and [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-ins, as well as the concept of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html). Those can reduce your task to an one-liner...

Comment: python 2 supports `range`. What version exactly are you talking about?

Comment: on python 3 `range` returns an iterator (or a generator, don't remember well), but python 2 returns a list. I should've been more clear.

Comment: It's usage in a for loop is still exactly the same between versions though.